# I am trying to run some powershell script on C# app to grant permission on Azure AD App, it works on Powershell but not on C# app

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to Grant permissions on Azure Active Directory Application using Powershell commands in c# application.
First I tried using below script in powershell.

```
Function Grant-OAuth2PermissionsToApp{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Username, #global administrator username
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Password, #global administrator password
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$azureAppId #application ID of the azure application you wish to admin-consent to
)

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $secpasswd)
$res = login-azurermaccount -Credential $mycreds
$context = Get-AzureRmContext
$tenantId = $context.Tenant.Id
$refreshToken = @($context.TokenCache.ReadItems() | where {$_.tenantId -eq $tenantId -and $_.ExpiresOn -gt (Get-Date)})[0].RefreshToken
$body = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6"
$apiToken = Invoke-RestMethod "https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
$header = @{
'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiToken.access_token
'X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'
'x-ms-client-request-id'= [guid]::NewGuid()
'x-ms-correlation-id' = [guid]::NewGuid()}
$url = "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/RegisteredApplications/$azureAppId/Consent?onBehalfOfAll=true"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -Method POST -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

This code granted the permission for Azure AD registered application.
I modified this script to run it in C# application.

```
Runspace runspace2 = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace2.Open();
        Pipeline pl = runspace2.CreatePipeline();
        pl.Commands.AddScript("Function Grant-OAuth2PermissionsToApp{ \n" +
            "$azureAppId = '" + appID + "'; \n" +
            "$username = '<login id >'; \n" +
            "$password = convertTo-securestring '<password>' -AsPlainText -Force; \n" +
            "$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password; \n" +
            "$res = login-azurermaccount -Credential $cred; \n" +
            "$context = Get-AzureRmContext; \n" +
            "$tenantId = $context.Tenant.Id; \n" +
            "$refreshToken = @($context.TokenCache.ReadItems() | where {$_.tenantId -eq $tenantId -and $_.ExpiresOn -gt (Get-Date)})[0].RefreshToken; \n" +
            "$body = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource=\"74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6\"'; \n" +
            "$apiToken = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/authorize?client_id=$azureAppId&response_type=code&&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FPowerBiApp.contoso.com&response_mode=query' -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; \n" +
            "$header = @{ \n" +
            "'Authorization'='Bearer '+$apiToken.access_token; \n" +
            "'X-Requested-With'='XMLHttpRequest'; \n" +
            "'x-ms-client-request-id'=[guid]::NewGuid(); \n" +
            "'x-ms-correlation-id'=[guid]::NewGuid(); \n" +
            "}; \n" +
            "$url = 'https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/RegisteredApplications/$azureAppId/Consent?onBehalfOfAll=true'; \n" +
            "Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -Method POST -ErrorAction Stop; \n" +
            "}");
        pl.Commands.AddScript("Grant-OAuth2PermissionsToApp");
        var r = pl.Invoke();
```

This gave me Parse error - Refresh Token is malformed or invalid.
I tried below things to get resolution:

1. in code after i get the value of `$refreshToken` i tried to split the string so that if I am getting token string twice I can select only one.

   `$refreshtoken = $refreshtoken.Split(''n')[0];`
2. somewhere i found that "-" we use in powershell script like `-AsPlainText` may get changed to endash. I recheck all the "-" being used in script.
3. another resolution i found that when we try to get refresh token using raw data we should use below url and parameters. I get this url form this [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)

   `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<ApplicationId>&response_type=code&&redirect_uri=<Application redirect Url>&response_mode=query`

These all things i tried did not work.
Is there any proper way to solve this issue?
Or Is there any other way to get RefreshToken which can be used to grant permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root cause is due to some powershell scripts are incorrectly converted to c# code.

I set a breakpoint in the c# code, and get the generated powershell scripts, then compare with your original powershell scripts. Some scripts in c# are enclosed with single quote, but in original powershell, it's enclosed with double quote, which may result some errors.

For example, in original powershell, this line of code: `$body = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6"`, but in your c# code(set a breakpoint to get the value), it's enclosed with single quote like `$body ='grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource="74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6"'`.

So please set a breakpoint at your c# code, and get the generated powershell scripts from c#, and make sure it's same as your original powershell scripts.

As per the comparison, there are 3 lines need to change in your c# code, you can replace the respective line with the following ones:

```
"$body = \"grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6\"; \n" +

"$apiToken = Invoke-RestMethod \"https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/authorize?client_id=$azureAppId&response_type=code&&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FPowerBiApp.contoso.com&response_mode=query\" -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; \n" +

"$url = \"https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/RegisteredApplications/$azureAppId/Consent?onBehalfOfAll=true\"; \n" +
```

Hope it helps.

Get the generated ps scripts from c# code:

[image]